How can I correctly write a Python filter function in Excel 365?
While working on a project, I wanted to use the filter function in excel in order to display things in a neat and professional fashion. Unfortunately, openpyxl (3.1.4) doesn't support the filter function, so one has to add it to the python code like this:
example = "=_xlfn.FILTER(Index!$D$4:$D$100,Index!$F$4:$F$100=\"JA\",\"\")"
ws['C4']= example

When the program runs, it enters the data into the workbook...with an @ at the beginning of the formula like so:
=@FILTER(Index!$D$4:$D$100;Index!$F$4:$F$100="JA";"")

This symbol causes the filter function to only display the first instance of an item instead of displaying the entire list.  Of course when one deletes the symbol everything works normally.
Of course I can manually delete it every time, but that would get annoying after a while since this program will be used quite often. How can I utilize this powerful feature in Python? Or do I need to just grin and bear it?

FYI requests for resource recommendations (which includes "is there a Python package for X") are generally off-topic here. Better to instead just ask how to achieve something in Python, and if the solution is "use package X", then that's fine.

@python_noob Try this: ws['C4'].value = re.sub(r'@', '', ws['C4'].value)

Excel adds the "@" in the GUI automatically, just like it does the translation and the unhelpful transcription of "," to ";" in separators and "." to "," in numbers.

Short answer
I am afraid you cannot use Dynamic array formulas and spilled array behavior with OpenPyXL up to now. The spilled array behavior was introduced in Excel version 365. It is not usable in former versions. OpenPyXL was introduced and bases on specifications when Excel Version was 2007 (the first version using Office Open XML and *.xlsx file format).
But why the @ symbol?
This get described in Implicit intersection operator: @:

The @ symbol is ... used ... to indicate implicit intersection. ...
the @ indicates that the formula should use implicit intersection to
retrieve the value

If OpenPyXL stores the FILTER formula, then it does this like Excel versions before 365 would store formulas. It not considers spilled array behavior, which would need to store special cell metadata to describe the spilled array behavior - spilling values over as much cells as needed. There are not even classes for those metadata in OpenPyXL up to now. Thus, when Excel opens the file, it finds a FILTER formula without  spilled array behavior, which cannot work correctly and only returns one value. It marks that with @.
Can you remove the @?
Not really, I am afraid. As said you cannot use dynamic array formulas and spilled array behavior using OpenPyXL up to now.  One could use FILTER in old array formula context. But that needs to know the size of the resulting array as old array formulas not are dynamic and explicitly not spilling their values over as much cells as needed.
Example:
from openpyxl import Workbook
from openpyxl.worksheet.formula import ArrayFormula  
wb = Workbook()

ws = wb.create_sheet("Index", 1)
ws['D3'] = ""
data = [{'D':"D4"}, {'D':"D5", 'F':"JA"}, {'D':"D6"}, {'D':"D7", 'F':"JA"}, {'D':"D8"}]
for row in data:
    ws.append(row)
    
ws = wb.active;
formula = "=_xlfn.FILTER(Index!$D$4:$D$100,Index!$F$4:$F$100=\"JA\",\"\")"
ws['C4'] = ArrayFormula('C4:C5', formula)

wb.save('excelResult.xlsx')


Thank you for your explanation. This makes perfect sense.

FWIW support for metadata will be in 3.2 but only as per the specification.
